# How to prevent the default inplace add `__iadd__` calling the reflected add `__radd__` of my class in Python?

Tags: python, addition, magic-methods, in-place

I have a class where I have defined the reflected add (`__radd__`) special method:

```py
class Addable:
    def __init__(self, other=0):
        if isinstance(other, Addable):
            self.id = other.id
        else:
            self.id = other
    def __add__(self, other):
        print(f'Called add of {self.id}')
        other = Addable(other)
        return Addable(self.id+other.id)
    def __radd__(self, other):
        print(f'Called radd of {self.id}')
        other = Addable(other)
        return Addable(self.id+other.id)
```

The object is designed so adding with another type, such as an int, works fine. e.g. `Addable(0) + 1` and `0 + Addable(1)`.

However, this also works:

```
x = 1
y = Addable(2)
x += y
assert isinstance(x,Addable) and x.id  == 3
```

`x` becomes `Addable(3)` because the reflected add of Addable was used. I don't want this operation to be possible as its unintuitive for my use case as `x`'s type changes by doing a inplace add. This is described in the [Python data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ior__):

> `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)` [if defined]. Otherwise, `x.__add__(y)` and `y.__radd__(x)` are considered.

**How can I prevent Python from using the reflected add method (`__radd__`) of my class for inplace add (`__iadd__`) for another class? Is there a way I can detect in the `__radd__` method that its being used in an inplace add `__iadd__`?**

Comment: One idea is to check `if isinstance(other, Addable)` In the definition of `__radd__` and raise an error in case it is not.

Comment: This looks sloppy. The root of the problem is your class is forcibly casting `other` to `Addable` -- if you want to respect the type of the argument, you need to actually implement the corresponding type logic in the function. What is you are trying to do with this, and why do you need `__radd__` in the first place

Comment: I want the object to be addable with basic types such as int. However, `x += y` doesn't intuitively make sense as the type of `x` changes from an inplace operation - this should raise a type error.

Comment: For example, a numpy array has the same characteristics.
`import numpy as np` A) `assert 1 + np.array([2]) == np.array([3])` B) 
`assert np.array([2]) + 1 == np.array([3])` C) `x = 1; x += np.array([2]); assert x == np.array([3]);`